# How to calculate checksum from known data?

Tags: crc

I'm trying to create the algoritm to produce the actual checksum byte (D0) in a vehicle 11-bit CAN bus message, where all values are known by scanning the current bus (which I'm trying to replicate with other values, but I cant find the mathematical relation between data and checksum byte).

here are the sample data (in hex): 
**D0    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7** 
9F  70  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  00 
A9  7A  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  00 
AA  7B  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  00 
AB  7C  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  00 
AB  7C  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  00 
0D  7D  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
0E  7E  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
09  79  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
0A  7A  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
0B  7B  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
Some more data with the same checksum(0xFF) at D0:
**D0    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7** 
FF  70  FC  70  FC  0D  0F  60 
FF  74  F9  70  F9  0D  0F  62 
FF  17  01  20  01  0D  0F  02 
FF  AE  0D  70  0D  0D  0F  02 
FF  13  13  0   13  0D  0F  02 
FF  B8  10  60  10  0D  0F  02 
FF  56  11  C0  11  0D  0F  02 
FF  0D  2D  D0  2E  0D  0F  02 
Some more with another known and same checksum (0x16):
**D0    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7** 
16  7E  FF  70  FF  0D  0F  62 
16  7E  FF  70  FF  0D  0F  62 
16  F0  03  50  0B  0D  0F  02 
16  78  13  B0  13  0D  0F  02 
16  F9  2E  00  27  0D  0F  02 
16  EE  FF  60  FF  0D  0F  02

D0 = checksum 
D1,D2,D3,D4 = torque values (critical) 
D5 = Engine coolant temp 
D6,D7 = No important engine data

Anyone?

Comment: Having so many messages with the same checksum strikes me as odd. I tried typical bytewise addition and it gets you close, but it's always off by a bit. For example for the 0x16 messages I can calculate 0x6A and 0x6C. If they were the same you could just assume a hidden constant and fix it but it's odd. Xor seems to perform worse. I don't think it's a complex algorithm but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's obviously not a checksum if the following bytes are different for the same initial value. It looks more like a control/message/id byte to me.

Comment: I think it is: ((D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7)-85)&0xFF, I will verify it today, but sometimes it does not match, like +/-1 what it should be, very strange.

Comment: ((D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7)-85)&0xFF, getting close, but it is not the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

OP was getting close with `D0=((D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7)-85)&0xFF`. That's not the correct method (sometimes it's off by 1), but consider the values of `(D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7)-D0`: for the given data, it has the values `['-0xa8', '0x57', '0x156', '0x255', '0x354']`.

What's the common property? Yes, they're all divisible by `0xFF` when subtracted by `0x57`.

Therefore, the checksum byte is the sum of all bytes, subtract `0x57`, modulo `0xFF`, then if the result is `0` then replace it with `0xFF`. (alternatively this can be written as `(sum - 0x58) % 0xFF + 1`)

It is impossible for the checksum byte to be 0.